# Delphi - Graphics32, draw multiple transparent PNG over JPG as watermak

Tags: delphi, graphics32

After read Graphics32 documentation I can't find a objetive example of use layers.

I just want to compose the following Image:

- Layer 1 - Background Image (In JPG) (800x600)
- Layer 2 - Transparent PNG as a frame border (800x600)
- Layer 3 - Transparent PNG on right bottom with 25º Rotation (90x90)

And this is the expected result:

[image]

```
// uses => GR32, GR32_Layers, GR32_Png, GR32_Image;
procedure TMain.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
// src, dest: TPNGObject; <-- another frustrating try
// r: TRect;
   bmp: TBitmap32;
   png: TPortableNetworkGraphic32;
   rlayer: TCustomLayer;
   img1, img2, img3: TImgView32;
begin
   bmp := TBitmap32.Create;
   bmp.Assign(imgPreview.Picture); // TImage obj already have a JPG loaded

   img1 := TImgView32.Create(nil);
   img1.Bitmap := bmp;

   img2 := TImgView32.Create(nil);
   img2.Bitmap.LoadFromFile('C:\\layer2.png');

   img3 := TImgView32.Create(nil);
   img3.Bitmap.LoadFromFile('C:\\watermark.png');

   rlayer := TCustomLayer.Create(nil);
   rlayer.LayerCollection.Add(img1.Layers.Items[0]); // [DCC Error]  Incompatible types: 'TLayerClass' and 'TCustomLayer' ????

   ...
```

How can I add a new layer to collection? And after all, how can I save this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `LayerCollection.Add` method expects to receive a value of type `TLayerClass`. That is, it wants to receive the *class*, not an *instance* of a class. To satisfy the compiler, pass it *literally* `TCustomLayer`; the collection will instantiate the given class itself. It will *return* the instance reference. See for yourself in [*GR32_Layers.pas*](http://sourceforge.net/p/graphics32/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/Source/GR32_Layers.pas#l413).

However, you're taking the wrong approach to begin with. `TBitmap32` objects don't have layers. A `TImage32` component has layers, which is useful if you want to not only display multiple bitmaps layers together, but also allow the user to interact with the layers; you'd detect which layer is which with the `HitTest` method, as described in the [layer overview](http://graphics32.org/documentation/Docs/Additional%20Topics/Using%20TImage32/Using%20Layers.htm). Each layer consists of one graphic; for bitmaps, you probably want to use `TBitmapLayer`, not just `TCustomLayer`.

Just to create a new bitmap, you don't need layers at all. (And as long as you're using a Delphi version that understands PNG images, I'm pretty sure you don't even need Graphics32.) Instead, just start with a blank bitmap. Paint the main bitmap where it needs to go, then paint the frame bitmap, and then paint the stamp bitmap. Finally, save the bitmap.

Unless you're actually going to display all the separate bitmaps on a form, you don't need those `TImgView32` components. That component is for displaying images on the screen with scroll bars.

Comment: I'm using Delphi 2007 (doesn't support native PNG) - I'm reading source code of Layers example to try understand this concept. Thanks!